# Recursion decomposition in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn recursion. Having trouble decomposing an exercise to draw a recursive tree- in the code below the base case includes the function window.drawPolarLine(branchbase, length, angle) which returns the GPoint (x and y) of the end of the branch its just drawn. Any recursive solution is going to have to keep track of a large number of GPoints. I can't work out if that's supposed to happen in the stack frames, or if I'm supposed to use a vector to store them. Using a vector would seem to be heading down the road of an iterative solution?

Anyway, this is my very messy code so far;

```
/**
 * File: trees.cpp
 * ---------------
 * Draws a recursive tree as specified in the Assignment 3 handout.
 */

#include <string>    // for string
#include <iostream>  // for cout, endl
using namespace std;

#include "console.h" // required of all CS106 C++ programs
#include "gwindow.h" // for GWindow class and its setTitle, setColor, and drawPolarLine methods
#include "gtypes.h"  // for GPoint class
#include "random.h"  // for randomChance function

const static double kWindowWidth = 600;
const static double kWindowHeight = 600;
const static string kWindowTitle = "Recursive Trees";
const static double kTrunkLength  = kWindowHeight/4;
const static double kShrinkFactor = 0.70;
const static int kBranchAngleSeparation = 15;
const static int kTrunkStartAngle = 90;
const static string kLeafColor = "#2e8b57";
const static string kTrunkColor = "#8b7765";
const static double kBranchProbability = 1.0;

static GPoint drawTree(GWindow& window, int order, GPoint branchBase, double length, int angle, Vector<GPoint>& branches);

const static int kHighestOrder = 5;
int main() {
    GWindow window(kWindowWidth, kWindowHeight);
    window.setWindowTitle(kWindowTitle);
    cout << "Repeatedly click the mouse in the graphics window to draw " << endl;
    cout << "recursive trees of higher and higher order." << endl;
    GPoint trunkBase(window.getWidth()/2, window.getHeight());
    Vector<GPoint> branches;
    for (int order = 0; order <= kHighestOrder; order++) {
        waitForClick();
        window.clear();
        drawTree(window, order, trunkBase, kTrunkLength, kTrunkStartAngle, branches);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "All trees through order " << kHighestOrder << " have been drawn." << endl;
    cout << "Click the mouse anywhere in the graphics window to quit." << endl;
    waitForClick();
    return 0;
}

static GPoint drawTree(GWindow& window, int order, GPoint branchbase, double length, int angle, Vector<GPoint>& branches) {
    if (order == 0) {

        GPoint base = window.drawPolarLine(branchbase, length, angle);
        branches.add(base);
        return branchbase;
    }

        window.setColor(order < 2 ? kLeafColor : kTrunkColor);

        branchbase = branches.get(order - 1);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 45, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 30, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 15, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 15, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 30, branches);
        drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 45, branches);


        return drawTree(window, order - 1, branchbase, length * kShrinkFactor, angle, branches);
    }
    // update this function to wrap around another version of drawTree, which
    // recursively draws the tree of the specified order....
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires a slightly different approach than the classical recursion examples (like sorting), where the problem-set is reduced on each recursion and there is a natural limit (problem-size <= 1).

With this problem, the amount of information increases exponentially with the order of the tree. This make it impractical to draw an third order tree by first drawing a second order tree and having the function return to you where (and with which angle) those branches ended, so you could add the third order branches to it.

For this kind of problem, it is much easier to write the recursive function like this:

```
void drawTreeOrder(GWindow& window, int curr_order, int max_order, GPoint branchBase, double length, int angle)
{
    /* Check if there is more work to do */
    if (curr_order >= max_order)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* Draw a branch */
    window.setColor(curr_order - max_order < 2 ? kLeafColor : kTrunkColor);
    GPoint end = window.drawPolarLine(branchBase, length, angle);

    /* Draw the higher-order branches starting from the current one */
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 45, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 30, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle - 15, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 15, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 30, branches);
    drawTreeOrder(window, order + 1, max_order, end, length * kShrinkFactor, angle + 45, branches);
}

/* Convenience function, so the caller does not have to bother with curr_order */
void drawTree(GWindow& window, int max_order, GPoint branchbase, double length, int angle)
{
    drawTreeOrder(window, 0, max_order, branchBase, length, angle);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. That throws the whole tree up on the first click and then removes it in stages on each succeeding click, from the outer leaves to the trunk. But it's very close to being what the exercise requires- which is to draw the tree in stages starting from the trunk, going out to the leaves.